# How to Kickstart Kubeflow Pipeline development in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines

I have been studying about Kubeflow and trying to grasp how do I write my first hollo world program in it and run locally on my mac. I have `kfp` and `kubectl` installed locally on my machine. For testing purpose I want to write a simple pipeline with two functions: `get_data()` and `add_data()`. The doc is overwhelming that I am not clear how to program locally without k8s installed, connecting remote GCP machine and debug locally before creating zip and upload or there way to execute code locally and see how is it running on Google cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you need Kubernetes to run KFP pipelines.

The easiest way to deploy KFP is when you use the [Google Cloud Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-ai-platform/kubeflow-pipelines?filter=solution-type%3Ak8s&filter=price%3Afree&filter=category%3Adeveloper-tools)

Alternatively you can locally install Docker Desktop which includes Kubernetes and install [standalone](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/installation/standalone-deployment/#deploying-kubeflow-pipelines) version of KFP on it.

After that you can try this tutorial: [Data passing in python components](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/samples/tutorials/Data%20passing%20in%20python%20components.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can install a reduced version of kubeflow with minikf. More info https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/minikf/minikf-vagrant/

Check whether you are using kubeflow pipelines from the google cloud marketplace, or a custom kubernetes cluster. If you are using the managed one, you can see your pipeline running through the kubeflow pipelines management console.

for details about how to create components based on functions, you can check https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/python-function-components/#getting-started-with-python-function-based-components